# How to reach HTTP Request in Java class

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor, struts2-interceptors

I want to see the request to the web page in an Interceptor I wrote. I will change my response value according to some values in the incoming request.I'm gonna use something like that ;

```
String ex = request.getHeader("GET");
if(ex.contains("addHeader("a","example")"));
     response.setHeader("a","null");
```

Here is my index.ft:

```
Your name: <@s.url value="${name}"/>
Enter your name here:<br/>
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is part of my TestInterceptor.java class;

```
public class TestInterceptor implements Interceptor {
....
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("before");

    //the area where I want to write the codes I want to use above
    // I can't to reach request.getHeader(...) function in here
    String result = ai.invoke();
    System.out.println("after");
    return result;
}
```

What's the solituon or another way to use that functions.
Thanks for helping.
Note : I'm using Struts framework

Comment: FWIW: this kind of question is almost *always* self-answerable with a tiny bit of research. Spending a few minutes with the Javadocs would lead down the path to the answer.

Comment: I'm equally tired of people that don't follow the Javadocs (which lead to the answer in 2-4 clicks) or cracking open an existing interceptor to just *look* at it. Here's the thing: you *can* solve it by following the trail of the docs and the code. This is pretty much one of like three skills every developer needs: the ability to follow trails. (The other two being regex and recursion.)

Comment: Also, in addition to neglecting due diligence in reading Javadocs and/or code, searching the web for "struts 2 interceptor access request headers" leads to multiple answers, including on SO, which makes the question a dupe anyway. So four skills every developer needs, adding "searching the web".

Comment: you are exactly right :)) walk to work

Comment: Bike for me ;) Please don't interpret my comments negatively--they're intended to help, not hurt. I'll also update some of the S2 docs to include this information more directly and clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from ActionContext

```
ActionContext context = ai.getInvocationContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(HTTP_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modifty your request before the request HTTP is triggerd (e.g before the `Action` has executed and before the `Result` is executed).

`PreResultListener` allows us to do just that. Your `TestInterceptor` should implement `PreResultListener` and provides implementation of the `beforeResult()` method. In this method, we get the `HttpServletResponse` object from the `ActionContext` and add custom logic to it.

**For your case : modifying header value**

The `TestInterceptor` registers itself with the ActionInvocation in the before method, which gets a callback before the result is executed.

```
public class TestInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor implements  PreResultListener {

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
  before(invocation);
    return invocation.invoke();
}

private void before(ActionInvocation invocation) {
  invocation.addPreResultListener(this);
}

private void modifyHeader(Object action, HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.addHeader("myHeader", "myValue");
}

public void beforeResult(ActionInvocation invocation, String resultCode) {
  ActionContext ac = invocation.getInvocationContext();
  HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ac.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);
  modifyHeader(invocation.getAction(), response);  
}
}
```